# Application Insights Live Metrics with ASP.Net MVC and Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

we want to monitor one of our application with Azure Application Insights. It is an ASP.Net 4 MVC application with Web Api 2. I've created a new Application Insights resource in Azure and I've installed the following NuGet packages into the project:

```
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.7" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

The ApplicationInsights.config looks like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
<!-- This key is for Application Insights resource 'PlanningTool.Web' in resource group 'Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS' -->
<InstrumentationKey>Our key</InstrumentationKey>
<TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    <!--
    Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:

    <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
    </Counters>

    PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

    NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

    The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
    -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
    <Handlers>
        <!-- 
        Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

        NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
    </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</TelemetryModules>
<TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    </Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
<!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
-->
<TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DomainNameRoleInstanceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
    <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

But Application Insights does for exmample not show the live metrics or the server requests.

I've tried the access to App Insights, via a test program, which is woring, all data (Live metrics, requests, etc.) were shown correctly:
    using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
    using System;

```
namespace AppInsightsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application Insights Test");
            var e = new Exception("This is a App Insights test");
            var ai = new TelemetryClient();
            ai.TrackException(e);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have to configure App Insights in an MVC/Web Api project so that it works correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Update with screenshots form Visual Studio (2017) and Azure Portal:
VS:
[image]

Azure Portal (in german):
[image]

Comment: Is Live Metric the only thing that doesn't work? Do you see regular telemetry (requests, dependencies, events, exceptions)?
One weird thing I see in your configuration is that QuickPulseTelemetryModule is mentioned twice, once correctly and once inside of the <TelemetryProcessors> tag. Try removing the second occurrence and see if it changes the behavior.

Comment: @tokaplan: Thanks for the hint with QuickPulseTelemetryModule. I've removed it. And in Application Insights I don't see anything at all, no requests, etc. I've now set up a minimal example that is based on the Visual Studio MVC template. I've installed all application insights packages via NuGet, but this project does also not send any telemetry data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After ignoring this task for a long time I've finally found the answer. The service is hosted behind a company proxy and to enable it send the data to azure you've to add the proxy to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
     <system.net enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
         <proxy proxyaddress="http://url.to.your.proxy" bypasslocal="true" />
     </system.net>
</configuration>
```

You have to adopt the settings dependent of your proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I add Application Insights to my existing MVC project with the following steps, I can get live metrics stream and server requests metrics, please refer to it.

- Right-click web app project in Solution Explorer, and choose Add >
  Application Insights Telemetry... , and then register app with
  Application Insights and configure Application Insights. (Which will help us install Application Insights related packages and configure projects.)
- Open web pages to generate some telemetry
- On Azure portal, I can see the number of online servers and Live metrics stream.

  [image]
- Add chart to show server requests

  [image]

  [image]

Besides, you could also refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net) that shows how to configure your ASP.NET web app to send telemetry to the Azure Application Insights service.

Comment: In Visual Studio I can see the requests etc. (see the update of my question). But in the azure portal there is nothing. I can't see any online servers. Where can I change the chart details? When I've used my test console application I was able to see the live metrics, and anything else.

Comment: Under *Metrics Explorer* blade, you will find [Add chart] button on the top of web page.

Comment: I've changed the diagram settings, but no request were logged at all. I've also redone the setup that was described in our link.

Comment: Please try to create a new ASP.NET MVC project and follow the above steps to configure the app to send telemetry to the Azure Application Insights service, and check if it works fine.

Comment: I've did like described in the link (step by step), but still no luck...

Comment: Do you click **Register** to go ahead and configure Application Insights for your web app or just add the Application Insights SDK to try local only mode? Besides, you cannot see any data, please make sure the time range is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure application insights resource is not linked to your web application.

In Azure portal find your Application Insights resource and navigate to Configure->Properties.

There you will find "INSTRUMENTATION KEY".

Copy that key to your applicationInsights.config section:

```
<InstrumentationKey>Our key</InstrumentationKey>
```

Comment: I've removed our real key for the example here. Locally I've entered our correct key.

Comment: Ok. In your Azure portal, in your web app properties, can you see an Application Insights option? Have you configured that to use your App insights resource?