# Get certain page view count from appinsights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

We hosted the MVC application in Azure and enabled app-insights in the application through nuget packages. Now, we wanted to read the pageviews from the appinsights for certain URLS from the MVC application. 
I referred the following links but it didnot explain how to read the appinsight page views count based on the URL

[AppInsight live stream in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701228/application-insights-live-metrics-with-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api)

[AppInsights - Page counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-users)

Please help if you have better solutions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the overview blade, you should have a link to **Analytics**. This will provide a sql-like query experience against the AppInsights data.

When Analytics loads, I would start by double clicking on *pageViews* under *Application Insights*. This will load the default pageViews query (all page views in last 24h). The query results will include the url and more data about the page load. You can use the query editor to filter down to the data you are interested in, and there is a chart tab that will allow you to visualize the results of your query.